# How to merge two csv file vertically and keep the data formate (number to number, string to string)

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, export-to-csv

I want to merge two csv file vertically. One file contain only strings (first column, first three rows). Second file contain strings and numbers.

I can print them out. But have problem to save them row by row to a csv file. Also have problem to keep the data type. (number to number, string to string).

The following is the code I used :

Method 1:

```
import csv


file1 = ("/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/String_.csv")
file2 = ("/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/CovertFile_SampleData4.csv")


combined_file = ("/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/combined_file.csv")
spreadsheet_filenames = [file1,file2]

for filename in spreadsheet_filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        output = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in output:
            print row
```

The following is my print results:

```
['SoftGenetics GeneMarker Trace Data Export']
['Raw Data']
['PAT_Ladder_1.fsa']
['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Orange']
['82.45', '97.65', '229.05', '85.25', '44.85']
['151.08', '167.48', '454.48', '136.68', '59.28']
['144.45', '161.25', '440.25', '133.65', '60.45']
['49.5', '65.9', '105.5', '69.1', '44.5']
['73.25', '109.45', '326.65', '70.85', '26.85']
['66.58', '97.18', '322.58', '65.38', '24.78']
['56.95', '77.35', '138.35', '91.95', '61.75']
['66.45', '79.65', '351.05', '69.25', '35.25']
```

The following is the code I used to write csv file that save all data to a new csv file. I found that csv file was not created correctly.

```
import csv


file1 = ("/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/String_.csv")
file2 = ("/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/CovertFile_SampleData4.csv")


combined_file = ("/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/combined_file.csv")
spreadsheet_filenames = [file1,file2]

for filename in spreadsheet_filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        output = csv.reader(csvfile)
        with open(Combined_File, mode='w') as Combined_File:
            for row in output:
                print row
                csv_writer = csv.writer(Combined_File, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**Method 2:**

**By using "dataframe.concat". I consider file one and file two as two objects (dataframes). merged is the dataframe I expected. But file "combined_file.csv" wasn't created/ generated by df.to_csv method here. And there is no error message.**

```
f1 = pd.read_csv(file1, header=None)
f2 = pd.read_csv(file2, header=None)
merged = pd.concat([f1, f2])
merged.to_csv(combined_file, index=None, header=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) takes a list of dataframes as its first argument.

Try:

```
merged = pd.concat([f1, f2])
```

Comment: I updated the code. It was correctly merged to a new dataframe "merged". But I can't save the dataframe to csv file by using "merged.to_csv" which is abnormal. It doesn't give me any error message though.

Comment: That seems weird. Are you sure you checked the location where you are trying to save the csv file? Maybe try changing the path?

Comment: Since it is able to read in file1 and file 2, path "/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807" exits. I thought /combined_file.csv is supposed to be created in this way.

Comment: It's possible that the folder is write-protected. That's why I suggested you change the path and double check if your script is working fine or not. Then you know what to fix.

Comment: Haha great! Please accept the answer, if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the file twice! `open(Combined_File, mode='w')` overwrites the file and since it is inside the loop, you will only get data from the last file.

Another hint is that you can use `writerows()` to write multiple rows with a single call, and it takes an iterable, so you can just pass `csv_input` to write everything:

```
import csv

file1 = "/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/String_.csv"
file2 = "/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/CovertFile_SampleData4.csv"
spreadsheet_filenames = [file1, file2]
combined_file = "/Users/yingdu/GitHub/20180807/combined_file.csv"

with open(combined_file, 'w') as output_file: # create output outside the for loop
     csv_output = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',') 
     for filename in spreadsheet_filenames:
         with open(filename) as input_file:
             csv_input = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')
             csv_output.writerows(csv_input)
```